# :focus-withing not working for hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

I've made this hover effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/fwgh7bca/

**HTML & CSS**

```css
nav:hover ul li {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  margin: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And I want the effect to be applied when tabbing on the links. I tried adding this:

```
nav:focus-within ul li{
    opacity: 0.4;
}

nav ul li:focus{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But it doesn't work, how can I make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, it worked now (－‸ლ)

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use :focus for the `a` elements

```css
nav:hover ul li{
  opacity: 0.4;
}

nav ul li:hover{
  opacity: 1; 
}

nav ul li{
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body{
  margin: 5rem;
}

nav:focus-within ul li a{
    opacity: 0.4;
    color: yellow;
}

nav ul li a:focus{
    opacity: 1;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Number 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```